# How can I set a generic constraint to ensure that a common key between two types also has the same value type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm creating a function to copy fields from one object to another and I'd like to guarantee:

- I can only give a key that is common between both objects
- the given key corresponds to the same value type in both types

How can I implement the second constraint? Here's what I have so far.

```js
function copyField<T1, T2>(input: T1, output: T2, key: keyof T1 & keyof T2) {
  const keyValue = input[key]
  output[key] = keyValue // How can I ensure that the key value is the same for both?

  // ^ Error: Type 'T1[keyof T1 & keyof T2]' is not assignable to type 'T2[keyof T1 & keyof T2]'.
  // Type 'T1' is not assignable to type 'T2'. 'T2' could be instantiated with an
  // arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T1'.
}

type A = { field: string }
type B = { field: string }

copyField<A, B>({field: 'hello'}, {field: 'world'}, 'field')
```

[Live example on typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOAHAngMRgUwDYAmAPACoCMANIiQEwB8AFDGKiFAFzWWJxusfUaVANY50nUejjAuiAGSJJ0wQEpEAbwBQiZAgDOURWIBqAQzwgciALyJm-ANqSAutp582Tsc5tH0ZiysAeiDEAAk4AHdkUyQASUQcMD0QACcrKAALU0Msq0lEADdzSzs9RDzEPVMAWytgOFTEACM4LIB%20TTcQxAA9RABRVNTGzhJ0VCsAcnIvKRlyeT9lWmcpssQwNsRTPT0YAHMwU2a8DLgKienaOZWyJaUFmjWAOm7Q8cnEGbJ1mHKtoZdvsjiczhULlArt9aFMXjCaOsUCBCC0rMwDLFYDkcAREJEYFkdmB3jtUs1CalTKl0JcvpFMjAIJldCi8c0rOB0ngcXioBcfnDNABfLpQr4AQV86kQwFwhE4BlSzAOiFF4qsACFpbL5QRFVBlWBVaLNCgMNh8MQJVRNYx1HKrZwppl8Hg4FNhVQHXrnZFGoRPVQpo7AyogA)

### Update

An answer below got me closer to what I want but still doesn't guarantee that the value for the given key is exactly the same. This demonstrates how mismatched types can still compile because the constraint only guarantees that the type is present *somewhere* on both objects, not necessarily for the given key.

```js
function copyField<K extends string, V>(input: {[k in K]: V}, output: {[k in K]: V}, key: K) {
  const keyValue = input[key]
  output[key] = keyValue
}

type A = { s: string, mismatch: string }
type B = { s: string, mismatch: number }
//                                 ^--- these don't have the same type

const a: A = {s: 'hello', mismatch: 'hello'}
const b: B = {s: 'world', mismatch: 123}

// This compiles, but I want it to only accept 's'
copyField(a, b, 'mismatch')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
type CommonKeys<S, T> = {
    [K in keyof S & keyof T]:
        [S[K], T[K]] extends [T[K], S[K]] ? K : never
}[keyof S & keyof T]
```

It works by first constructing a mapped object type like `{s: 's', mismatch: never}`, then mapping that to `'s' | never` which is of course `'s'`.

Each key `K` is included if `[S[K], T[K]] extends [T[K], S[K]]`, which checks that `S[K]` and `T[K]` are subtypes of each other, i.e. the same type. If this is too strict for what you want, you could change this to `S[K] extends T[K]` to check only that the input value type is assignable to the output value type.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKBGANFARpgEx4DGmALFAL4BQokUAQgsmprgZgMx4AmmAKw1a9cNADCAewC2MqQDsA0hBABnADwBlPABUAfKyS0opqAG0lUAJYKoAa1VSAZlC1QAZA6evdAXUxzLUs-PRC-KAgAD2AIBT41C10QvGClPwiAfigrTAUIADcIACdaanNHEBc3T28q3z9RBmhdCDVgVmk5RRV1DRg8Jn1aAHoRqFb21gByVGnaIA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Why is your playground example `'a'` and not both `'a' | 'b'`? Both `A` and `B` have those fields and both are numeric. Is it comparing the actual values themselves and not just the value *types*?

Comment: The type `2` means it can only have the value `2`, likewise the type `3` can only have the value `3`. So these two types have no possible common values.

Comment: Oh I didn't even realize value constraints were possible, however I'm looking for a looser constraint that only ensures the *type* of the values are the same, not the values themselves

Comment: @geg You are misunderstanding - `2` and `3` are types. They are singleton types. You can use whatever types you want, I just used them as examples of two types with no overlap; replace them with `number` and `string` if that makes more sense to you. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigM10JPIGNMCB7JgGwlSygF8AoUSFABCCZGir4iZCpgDOwYgEssAc3IATRi3acevfuGgBhJnjxMsAaQghZAHgDK5ACoA+UUl5RvUANqWoZSgAaxsmADMoBygAMhCwyOcAXUxfB38klwykqAgAD2AILHVZP2cM8nTLJJyAfigAqggANxJebl9QkAio2PjuxKT9AWhnCHlREzMLa1s7GHIhV14AehWoMYnEAHJUbd4gA)

Comment: Ahh I misread it because I didn't realize they could be used as types. Thanks, this did the trick.

Comment: One last question, are there terms to describe the syntax that you used? I understand you explanation but don't intuitively understand the operator precedence. Specifically, how much of the leading expression is part of the ternary expression? Also, what is `[keyof S & keyof T]` doing at the end and how does it interact with the prior stuff?

Comment: `[S[K], T[K]] extends [T[K], S[K]]` is the condition in the ternary expression, the part before the `:` is what makes it a mapped type, a bit like looping over the keys in `keyof S & keyof T`. The last part is the same syntactic form as `T[K]` - the part before the square brackets is a type, and the part inside the square brackets is another type which can be used to index it, resulting in the type of the values for those indices.

Comment: What if you want to compare more than 2 objects? Is there a way similar to accepting an array of object and find the common keys?

Answer (score 3):

In case it matters, here's how I'd think of doing it:

```
function copyField<O, K extends keyof O, I extends Record<K, O[K]>>(
    input: I,
    output: O,
    key: K
) {
    const i: Record<K, O[K]> = input;
    output[key] = i[key];
}
```

The idea is that you are allowing the type `O` of `output` be whatever you want, and allow the type `K` of `key` to be any key of `O`.  Then, the type `I` of `input` must be constrained to `Record<K, O[K]>` (see [docs for `Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)), meaning that `input` must be assignable to something with a property at key `K` whose value must be assignable to `O[K]`, the type of the same property in `O`.

Note that I'm not requiring that `I[K]` and `O[K]` be *identical*...  it should be sufficient to require that `I[K] extends O[K]` to allow good copies and disallow bad ones.

Also note: in order for the assignment to be accepted by the compiler inside the function implementation I needed to widen `input` from `I` to its constraint `Record<K, O[K]>`.

---

This gives the following desirable behavior:

```
copyField({ good: 0, bad: "", whatever: true }, { good: 4, bad: 1 }, "good"); // okay
copyField({ good: 0, bad: "", whatever: true }, { good: 4, bad: 1 }, "bad"); // error!
// ----------------> ~~~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

Note that the error here appears not on the `"bad"` value for `key`, but on the `input` parameter.  In this case, it specifically warns that the `bad` property is a `string`, but you can't write a `string` into a `number` property.

Similarly, the above definition will allow you to write from a narrow type into a wider type, but not vice versa:

```
copyField({ x: 123 }, { x: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 456 : "789" }, "x"); // okay
copyField({ x: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 456 : "789" }, { x: 123 }, "x"); // error!
// -------> ~
// Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

The first line works because it's safe to copy the `number` value from `input` into the wider `number | string` value from `output`.  But the second line complains because you cannot safely copy a `number | string` value from `input` into the narrower `number` value from `output`.  And the warning explains it.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#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)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
function copyField<K extends string, V>(input: {[k in K]: V}, output: {[k in K]: V}, key: K) {
  const keyValue = input[key]
  output[key] = keyValue
}

copyField({field: 'hello'}, {field: 'world'}, 'field')
```

Comment: While I thought this would work, it actually only makes sure that *some* property in both objects has the same type, not necessarily for the given key. I'll update the question with an example that demonstrates this